# How to read message from topic ActiveMQ PHP stomp persistent

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

In php I can read message from activeMQ with Stomp like that :

```
$consumer = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");
$consumer->clientId = "test";
$consumer->connect();
$consumer->subscribe("/topic/test");
$msg = $consumer->readFrame();

if ( $msg != null) {
    echo "Message '$msg->body' received from topic\n";
    $consumer->ack($msg);
} else {
    echo "Failed to receive a message\n";
}
```

But after read one message the php script end (seems logical), how can we have (like in JAVA) an always active consummer which can read message when a producer send it to the queue ?